# imacros detect object with dynamic changing id

Tags: imacros

I am making a script to detect a date picker and select some date from it. The issue is that my date picker has id which changes randomly and is auto generated. When i rerun the script it gives the error that object not found since date picker id is changed. Class name for my date picker is also not constant, the only thing constant is name.
Please help me how can i detect an object using name of the element or how can i pass my dynamically changing id of the element to my macro for my script to run successfully.

Comment: Just use the only attribute 'NAME'. (For more details give your code.)

Comment: EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#dp1420526309732" BUTTON=0 This is the code line with the dynamic id of my date picker.

Comment: The name of the date picker is event_date, it will be great help if  you could write the code line for me since I am new to languages

Comment: As I see you recorded the macro in ‘Experimental event recording mode’. But in your case you need to use so called ‘Select the best record mode automatically’. And your code must be something like this:  `TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=NAME:”event_date”`  or  `TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:”dp*”`  ('*' is a wildcard for any symbols) or  `...`  depending on the html-code of the web-page.

Answer (score 1):

http://imacros.net/best-practices-of-using-imacros-for-test-automation

1     Handling Dynamic IDs
 Use Wildcards
If you replace the numbers of the ID with the * wildcard, the macro will be successfully executed in every browser session.